# django pages cms file upload issue with django-storages for s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-cms, django-storage

Hi All and thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

I'm using django-pages-cms with s3_folder_storage http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-s3-folder-storage, an extension of django_storages https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/.

When I put an img placeholder in my template, the admin displays a file upload as expected. Before I set up my s3 credentials correctly, it also showed a 403 error from s3.

I chose a file in the admin and clicked submit. When the page reloads, it shows that the image has been stored. i.e. it lists a current image file.

However, I can't find the image file anywhere on my server or s3. When I load the page in the browser it points to the correct path on s3, but it can't load it because it doesn't exist.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can try to debug this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files were uploaded to a different folder on s3, as set in media root. My mistake!